# ePHP, MSSQL BETWEEN DATE function and "OR statements"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm writing a PHP script with MSSQL and MySQL. MSSQL is to connect to a database I have no control over, while the MySQL database I have control over.

When trying to retrieve data from the MSSQL database, I run into an issue with the SQL statement.

Below is my SQL statement:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM ScheduledCall WHERE StartTime BETWEEN '05-30-2014' 
        AND '06-09-2014' AND Title LIKE ('%Me%') OR Title LIKE ('%You%')";
```

The issue I run into is using the statement above is that the BETWEEN function no longer works. In the SQL statement I have "BETWEEN '05-30-2014' AND '06-09-2014'" so in theory it only should be showing everything after the 30th (No data) but instead its showing:

[image]

Now, after hours of playing around with the SQL statement, I realized if I remove "OR Title LIKE ('%You%') it works just fine.  How can I fix the SQL statement above to allow all my OR statements that follow? I need like at least 20 more OR TITLE LIKE statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ScheduledCall
WHERE StartTime BETWEEN '05-30-2014' AND '06-09-2014' AND
      Title LIKE ('%Me%') OR Title LIKE ('%You%');
```

Two things.  The more important is to use parentheses to get the logic that you want.  The second is to put the strings in the YYYY-MM-DD format (ISO standard).  So try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ScheduledCall
WHERE StartTime BETWEEN '2014-05-30' AND '2014-06-09' AND
      (Title LIKE '%Me%' OR Title LIKE '%You%');
```